# moving data of multiple excel files into multiple database tables using ssis

Tags: ssis

i have a scenario to create SSIS package Load different excel files in a folder to different SQL table with file name as table name, can any one help me

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you won't know the file names ahead of time, right? You just want to tell it which folder to use and have a variable pick up the file names, do the data flows, and name the tables?

Answer (score 0):

If All Sheets have same columns ,

a)Get List of Execelfile paths and destination server and table name into object variable

b) Get object record through foreach loop

c) Give Excel filepath variable in input expression and server ,table info at destination expression

each file will be loaded to  corresponding table